# C# Entity Framework - Upgrade production environments with migrations in separate branches

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration, entity-framework-migrations

We have 2 production environments deployed in separate branches old and new, (with different server versions, one emerged from another) and occasionally were merging migrations from the old version to the new without resolving any conflicts or testing an upgrade from old version to new (running the migrations of new server version on an already migrated DB, from the previous version).

Now, when trying to upgrade from the old version to the new one, the upgrade fails because the migrations are misordered (new migrations come before migrations that were already executed). Some migrations that were already executed on the old version were changed by their timestamp in the new version, causing it to be executed again in the upgrade and raising an error.

As a solution to this, an idea of mine was to reorder the migrations of the new version (by changing the timestamp) such as they are applied in the same order but **AFTER** all the migrations of the old version - this will support an upgrade from the old version to the new. For the new version to upgrade to the reordered migrations version I will **ONLY** update the **__EFMigrationsHistory** table with the new order, so in the end, I will have a version that supports both upgrades.

Is this a viable solution? Otherwise, I don't see a way to support 2 production branches with merged but unresolved migrations

Comment: Is there only one DB?

Comment: @CaiusJard yes, there is only one DB

Comment: To me it makes more sense to perhaps take the DB context and package it up as a nuget package, then you can update it/maintain it, keep the DB up to date, and both projects can reference the package. Any changes in the package that make code in (the old?) project not work any more are a problem that is resolved by updating the old code.. ?